# regex return array of matches

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my test string

`'Please disregard this.\r\n\r\n**Jonathan O\'Donnell: Estimated Time: 10 Hours.**\r\n\r\n**Jonathan O\'Donnell: 2 Hours May 15, 2015**\r\n**Chris Kuhar: 4 Hours May 30, 2015**'`

and this is my **Javascript** regex so far.

`/(\*\*.*?\*\*)/`

It matches the first occurrence perfectly but I want all occurrences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 /(\*\*.*?\*\*)/g
                ^^
```

The `g` modifier is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather **than stopping after the first match**).

If you want, you can storing a more detailed list using `.exec`, so, you also do a search within each match.

```js
var str = 'Please disregard this.\r\n\r\n**Jonathan O\'Donnell: Estimated Time: 10 Hours.**\r\n\r\n**Jonathan O\'Donnell: 2 Hours May 15, 2015**\r\n**Chris Kuhar: 4 Hours May 30, 2015**';

var reg = /\*\*([^:]+)\:\s*(.+)\*\*/g, fields = [], item;
while(item = reg.exec(str)){
   fields.push({name:item[1], time:item[2]})
}

console.log(fields)
```

```html
<script src="http://www.wzvang.com/snippet/ignore_this_file.js"></script>
```

Comment: @JonathanO You may want to accept this as correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `/g` in your regex expression which will search globally.

The g modifier is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match).

So final expression becomes `/(\*\*.*?\*\*)/g`

Answer (score 1):

Use string.match(/your regex/g); [ref](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)